# Covering addError in test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I built this error to fire off an exception when an account's SLA field with open cases is being changed, when it shouldn't.

Trigger

```
trigger DoNotAllowSlaChangesWithOpenCases on Account (before update) {

//Find the account's open cases
List<Account> accountsWithCases = [SELECT Id,
                                        (SELECT Id 
                                        FROM Cases 
                                         WHERE isClosed = false 
                                         LIMIT 1) 
                                   FROM Account 
                                   WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New];

//Check if the account's SLA field is changed
for (Account acc : accountsWithCases) {
    String oldSlaValue = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).SLA__c;
    String newSlaValue = Trigger.newMap.get(acc.id).SLA__c;
    Boolean isAccountSlaChanged = oldSlaValue != newSlaValue;
    //Check Open Cases
    Boolean accHasOpenCases = acc.Cases.Size() > 0;
    //Get the Trigger.new version of the account
    Account accInTriggerNew = trigger.newMap.get(acc.Id);
   //If SLA is changed and there are open cases
    if(isAccountSlaChanged && accHasOpenCases){
       accInTriggerNew.SLA__c.addError('Nope, not today baby!');
    }

}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class testDoNotAllowChangesWithOpenCases {

static testMethod void runaTest() {

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Class';
    acc.SLA__c = 'Gold';
    insert acc;

    Case c = new Case();
    c.Origin = 'Phone';
    c.Status = 'New';
    c.Priority = 'Medium';
    insert c;

    try {
       acc.SLA__c = 'Platium';
    update acc;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Nope, not today baby!'));
    }
    test.stopTest();

}

static testMethod void runaTest2() {
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Class';
    acc.SLA__c = 'Platinum';
    insert acc;

    Case c = new Case();
    c.Origin = 'Phone';
    c.Status = 'New';
    c.Priority = 'Medium';
    insert c;

    acc.SLA__c = 'Platium';
    update acc;

    test.startTest();        
    try {
        acc.SLA__c = 'Platium';
    update acc;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Nope, not today baby!'));
    }
    test.stopTest();
    }}
```

I am able to reach 88% code coverage with all of my code covered but can't seem to get the addError to be covered, are there any steps I should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglected to assign the AccountId to the case before inserting it:

```
...
insert acc;
...
c.AccountId = acc.Id;
...
```

By the way, in order to avoid regression bugs, you should include a false assertion:

```
try {
    acc.SLA__c = 'Platium';
    update acc;
    System.assert(false, 'Expected to receive an exception.');
}catch(Exception e){
    System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Nope, not today baby!'));
}
```

The false assertion will make sure that the exception is thrown or the test will fail.